# Paginacion en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Estoy siguiendo este ejemplo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview

Mi fichero js:

```
var App = angular.module('SimulatorApp',['ui.utils.masks','ui.bootstrap', 'angularModalService', 'datatables','ngSanitize', 'ui.tinymce']);

App.controller('TestController', [ '$window', '$location', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$q','$http', '$timeout', 'TestService', function($window, $location, $rootScope, $scope, $q, $http, $timeout, TestService) {    

$scope.filteredTodos = [];
$scope.currentPage = 1;
$scope.numPerPage = 10;
$scope.maxSize = 5;

$scope.makeTodos = function() {
  $scope.todos = [];
  for (i=1;i<=100;i++) {
    $scope.todos.push({ text:"todo "+i, done:false});
  }
};
$scope.makeTodos(); 

$scope.$watch("currentPage + numPerPage", function() {
  var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
  , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

  $scope.filteredTodos = $scope.todos.slice(begin, end);
});
```

Pero la paginación no me aparece:

```
<asset:stylesheet src="bootstrap.min.css"/> 
<asset:javascript src="angular.min.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="ui-bootstrap.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="bootstrap.min.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"/>

<pagination 
  ng-model="currentPage"
  total-items="todos.length"
  max-size="maxSize"  
  boundary-links="true">
</pagination>
```

He añadido también los js y css.

¿Cual es el que llama a ese tag?

Comment: He encontrado esta solucion alternativa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702042/how-to-use-ui-bootstrap-pagination-for-a-table-generated-using-ng-repeat

Answer (score -1):

- ¿Podrías poner tu controller?
- ¿Has añadido las referencias a la librería de bootstrap?

En ese ejemplo se están usando las directivas de UI Bootstrap. Te dejo aqui el enlace para que puedas acceder a ellas, por si te faltan.
[UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: he actulziado mi pregunta con lo que me pediste

Comment: Te marca algún mensaje en la consola que pueda ser significativo?

Comment: no me sale ningun error

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, si te fijas en la documentación que te pasé, las nuevas versiones de UI-Bootstrap no usan el tag <pagination> utilizan el <uib-pagination>